# How can I present customer data from spreadsheet into form in app maker for update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, client-server, google-app-maker

I have struggling to present available data for selected customer from spreadsheet into app maker form incase staff want to change it or update empty fields.
Client side code:

```
    function getDetails() {
  var props = app.currentPage.properties;
  var page = app.pages.Search;
  var Channel = app.datasources.Update.items;
  var Customer = page.descendants.Sheets.value;
  props.Loading = true;
  props.Error = null;
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(function(error) {
      props.Loading = false;
      props.Error = JSON.stringify(error);

      console.error(error);
    })
    .withSuccessHandler(function(Channel) {
     props.Loading = false;
     page.Channel = Channel; 
    var items = [];
   items =  getChannels(props.SelectedSheet);
    Channel.items.load();  // this line dosen't work and it doesn't load the data into form
      if (Channel && Channel.length > 0) {
        page.SelectedSheet = Channel[0];
      } })
    .getDetails(props.SelectedSheet);
}
```

Server side code:

```
function getDetails()(customer){
   var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("***").getSheetByName('TRACKER');
   var data=spreadSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
   var channels = [];
   var Name = customer;
   var string1 = Name;
   var array1 = string1.split(";"); // in here I extract row number belong to customer to get data
   var  destrow = [];  
   destrow.push(data[array1[0]][0],data[array1[0]][1],data[array1[0]][2],data[array1[0]][3],data[array1[0]][4],data[array1[0]][5]);
  channels.push(destrow);
//  return channels; 
  return channels.map(function(Channel){ 
  return Channel;}); // return array of field data to presented in app maker form
  }
```

Thank you for any answer or suggestion.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In theory, this code should throw exception, since `Channel` is array and array doesn't have `load` method:

```js
  function getDetails() {
    ...
    var Channel = app.datasources.Update.items;

    ...
    // your first Channel variable is never used and is overridden with
    // Channel callback parameter
   .withSuccessHandler(function(Channel) {
      // this line does nothing, since all App Maker objects are sealed
      page.Channel = Channel; 
      // TypeError: load is not a function
      Channel.items.load();
    ...   
  }
```

It is not clear from you code, what you are trying to do... Try to debug it and look into browser console more often (F12 or Ctrl + Shift + J).

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal